# Flash or FlashLite development for Android?

Tags: android, flash, flashlite

I'm investigating the possibility to develop Flash or FlashLite apps that runs on Android as stand-alone apps, but I'm not finding anywhere a clear, definitive and up-to-date answer. Questions:

- The HTC Hero supports Flash out-of-the-box (without installing it), right?...it's written everywhere, but which version? Flash 9? Flash 10? Flash Lite?
- Does the Google Nexus One supports Flash, out-of the box? Must it be installed separately?
- Can I develop Flash OR Flash Lite stand-alone apps for Android? What devices will they run on, today? (including Nexus One?)
- If "yes" to the previous version...is there any integration with the device capabilities? (camera, gps, access to contacts, accelerometer etc.)

I think a definitive answer to these questions will be useful to many out there!

The only programming example I found is this (http://www.flashmobileblog.com/2009/08/12/flash-development-with-android-sdk-1-5/) and it doesn't help much to understand what I can actually do with it...

Comment: @Nathan: I think I've simply asked questions for which nobody gave a final, correct answer...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Flash Version 10. You can launch standalone apps but not seamlessly, you need to ask the user to select the file. You've already read the [link supporting this.](http://www.flashmobileblog.com/2009/08/12/flash-development-with-android-sdk-1-5/)
2. [Not yet](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplatform/2010/01/flash_player_101_coming_to_goo.html)
3. As far as I know, using the method described in 1, you will be able to run Flash applications on the following devices (right now, nearly every device should have Flash 10/10.1 by the end of Q2 2010): HTC Hero, Droid Eris
4. No